# Delphi XE4 ios play videos not working... only sound

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I have this code in my Delphi XE / iOS project:

```
  MediaPlayerControl.MediaPlayer := MediaPlayer;
  MediaPlayerControl.Visible := True;
  MediaPlayer.FileName := FVideoPath;
  MediaPlayer.Play;
```

However, only the sound plays....

I have tried with both .mp4 video file (AFAIK supported) and another

Comment: MP4 videos can contain a variety of codecs. What codec is yours using?

Comment: Eg, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978165/why-does-mp4-video-plays-fine-on-ipad-not-on-iphone) about the wrong H264 baseline, for a video not playing on an iPhone. Check your video matches the [supported formats (see 'Video Technologies' section)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html). If it's an old iPhone, [check this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will investigate. I just tried a few different videos taken on my old (nokia) and current phone (android) - I was testing on iPhone4. (I have upvoted both comments)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the MediaPlayerControl of the project.
The video will play in full screen mode only.